# Can the profile page remember the last active "tab"?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

More and more I'm finding that the "stats" tab on my profile page is less useful than the others. For example, I often visit my profile page to look at the "recent" or "favorites" tabs.

Is there any chance that the site could remember which tab I last visited on my profile page, in much the same way that it remembers which tab I last visited on the /questions page? That way I can save a click if I keep visiting my profile page just to view favourites.

**Edit** Tom has suggested using a GreaseMonkey script, but I'm using IE (work machine), so I'd prefer something built in.

Answer (score 1):

How mad will you be if I say you can use greasemonkey to change your username link to [skip directly to a tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/615?tab=favorites)?  ;)