# Remember the profile tab I last visited

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

When I click another user's profile from the question list or from a post, 99% of the time I want to see how they recently have been interacting with the site, i.e. Activity --> All actions --> All.

However, clicking a username always defaults to showing their profile page, showing (above the fold) their badges and top tags. This takes two clicks and some waiting time to get me to the page I want to.

So: can the sites please remember which tab (Activity) and subtab (All actions) and subsubtab (All) I last viewed on any profile, and apply that to all future profile visits (including my own)?

Related:

- [Can the profile page remember the last active "tab"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22097/can-the-profile-page-remember-the-last-active-tab)
- [Remember if I was on the Activity tab when switching between Meta and Main user pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258014/remember-if-i-was-on-the-activity-tab-when-switching-between-meta-and-main-user)

Comment: I think I'd rather that be a user preference setting. This might cause confusion for people who don't know or forget how that works.

Comment: Sure, I'm open to that as well. Some parts of the profile (did?) remember where you were, I think it was the selected Activity subsubtab, i.e. if you last visited "Comments", it would default to the Comments tab for every profile you visited.